# A page without flash is triggering the following yellowbar in ie8

Tags: html, malware

This website wants to run the following add-on: Adobe Flash Player from ...

why would i be getting this if i am not running any flash on my page?? thanks

Comment: Do you have any ads on your page?

Comment: no, no adds, very little scripting just some seo stuff for google.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some toolbar or add-on trying to access it. Or most of the .cab or .dll uses the ActiveX. May be the reason but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and flash was triggered by the Google Analytics tracking code that was added to the page. However this doesn't happen on all IE8 setups. My configuration was Windows XP SP3, IE 8.0.6001.18702.

A quick workaround is disabling the flash tracking by adding `_gaq.push(['_setDetectFlash', false]);` just before `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`